# Discord Webhooks With C++

Tags: c++, windows, post, winsock, cloudflare

So I've taken up the challenge of doing webhooks in c++ and I wanted to just get some help with the post requests. Here is the code I have at the moment, I wanted to send embeds through post requests in C++.
Here is my code along with errors and all, the webhook is still active if you want to test yourself. Am trying to keep it all using windows librarys on purpose.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma warning(disable:4996) 
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int Plug(string address, string port, SOCKET* csock) {
    WSADATA WSAData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);

    PADDRINFOA result;
    ADDRINFOA hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(ADDRINFO));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    int res = getaddrinfo(address.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &result);
    *csock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == connect(*csock, (SOCKADDR*)result->ai_addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR))) return WSAGetLastError();
    return 0;
}

void Unplug(SOCKET* csock) {
    closesocket(*csock);
    WSACleanup();
}


string PostRequest(string host, string query, string data) {
    string req = "POST " + query + " HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n";
    req += "Host: " + host + "\r\n";
    req += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    req += "Content-Length: " + to_string(data.length()) + "\r\n";
    req += "Connection: Close";
    req += "\r\n\r\n" + data + "\r\n\r\n";
    SOCKET s;;
    Plug(host, "80", &s);
    Send(&s, req);
    while (GetAvailable(&s) == 0) Sleep(10);
    string result = Receive(&s);
    //if (result.find("\r\n\r\n") == string::npos && DEBUG) return result;
    //if (result.find("\r\n\r\n") == string::npos) return "PR_INVALID_RESPONSE";
    //result = result.substr(result.find("\r\n\r\n") + 4, string::npos);
    Unplug(&s);
    return result;
}
int main() {
    //https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/705211476553629747/zwzqZMnTTgLtHBm3kc_DvvD71IW9FfE4ur-PQlkgeZhd56cT7UjSJCWI-V8wPiEUWV2w
    std::cout<<PostRequest("162.159.129.233","/api/webhooks/705249405141516360/s8ioXr6IZEeuPnMi1O37CmY3o5pUZcu6ho7aIJdieSAqgGyTXOZjkOZdMNe1uJre6dto","{'embeds': [{'description': '**ERROR**: `TESTSTRING`\n', 'color': 4508791}]}");
}
```

However when I make the post requests it is unable to send my content and instead returns 400. I've tried a few more things but Im wondering if its my query?

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Cf-Ray: 58bd304dec1ff2c0-WAW
Cf-Request-Id: 026a1c84ad0000f2c054113200000001
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 00:36:28 GMT
Expires: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 01:36:28 GMT
Location: MYWEBHOOKURL
Server: cloudflare
Set-Cookie: __cfruid=5adc23f36cce3f0a398b8f9e91429b4349ef9314-1588206988; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

And lets say I use discords actual ip instead of resolving it I end up getting 
this instead

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: max-age=15
Cf-Ray: 58bd37782e6dffbc-WAW
Cf-Request-Id: 026a20ff1a0000ffbcc89df200000001
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 00:41:21 GMT
Expires: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 00:41:36 GMT
Server: cloudflare
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d4cb17401215362929759e2da8110f0e31588207281; expires=Sat, 30-May-20 00:41:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.162.159.129.233; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 16
Connection: close

error code: 1003
```

If you have any ideas dont hesitate to put them down below, ive been lost on this for a long time.

Comment: There's a commented out URL in the code. Is that the URL you are attempting to connect to? if so, do you know what "https" means, in that URL? Hint: it has nothing to do with http on port 80. And if you do really expect to talk on port 80, you're getting a very valid 301 response, which you must deal with. See RFC 2616 for more info. I note that it seems that you must also implement support for cookies, apparently. Or, maybe you should just give up and use a complete, full-featured, HTTP client library that handles these low-level HTTP details for you? Just a thought.

Comment: I am really trying to not rely on any other libraries, I am (if im not mistaken) able to call http requests to my URL. The issue comes from cloudflare blocking it since I cant really access http://162.159.129.233 (without getting blocked).

Comment: Nothing shown above indicates anything was blocked. You received a valid 301 response, which is a core part of the HTTP specification. HTTP isn't as simple as just making a socket connection, sending a request and waiting for the response. Sometimes you may get lucky, and that's all that's needed. But in this case, the API obviously wants  you to have a cookie, and you must resend the request, with the cookie. You have two options: either use a full HTTP library for this, or implement ***every part*** of the HTTP specification yourself, including cookies and redirects, see RFC 2616. Up to you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik 
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: max-age=15
Cf-Ray: 58bd37782e6dffbc-WAW
Cf-Request-Id: 026a20ff1a0000ffbcc89df200000001
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 00:41:21 GMT
Expires: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 00:41:36 GMT
Server: cloudflare
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d4cb17401215362929759e2da8110f0e31588207281; expires=Sat, 30-May-20 00:41:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.162.159.129.233; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 16
Connection: close

error code: 1003

Comment: The first reply, `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` was a valid HTTP redirect.

Comment: Ok so I understand that however the URL I provided was a valid URL, my webhook lives at that address, so why does it respond with moved permanently each time I try to access this url?

Comment: Please consider that Discord is using Cloudflare (WAF) to protect it's "backend" IP(s) so sending a request to their "IP" would actually be you sending a request to Cloudflare's DNS Server "covering" Discord's backend, hence the `301: Moved Permanently` response.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use D++ to post to webhooks:

https://dpp.dev/classdpp_1_1webhook.html

In fact you could do everything with this lib instead of rolling your own solution.